# Eloquent - Possibility to create relationship dynamically on query

Tags: laravel, eloquent, lumen

I have 2 models Coupon and Products.

A coupon can have several products.

The point is that it could be some different combinations (for example productA + productB, or productA OR productB, etc...)

So what I did was instead of making a relationship between Coupon and Products I instead store the products ID in my field like a string (for example: 1+2 which means that this coupon is available when both products are bought).

Probably not my best idea I confess...

Now my problem is that I need to make request on my coupons based on the products category (a field in my product model).
Is it possible to make a query like this (I initially thought I could achieve it with a scope on Coupon but I'm not able to do it), or is my database structure too bad this way and I should update it and use polymorphic relationship (not sure how I can do it either).

Here is my Coupon model :

```
class Coupon extends Model {
use Traits\Uuids;


protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::addGlobalScope(function ($query) {
        $query->hasProductCategory();
    });
}

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 
    'description',
    'products_id',
    'client_id',
    'facial_value',
    'image',
    'is_valid',
    'begin_date',
    'end_date',
    'use_case'
];

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'created_at', 
    'updated_at'
];


/**
 * Indicates if the IDs are auto-incrementing.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
public $incrementing = false;

/**
 * We define our default primary key.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $primaryKey = 'uuid';



/** 
* Define if coupon has multiple products or just one
* return bool
*/
public function scopeIsSingleProduct():bool
{
    $aProduct = explode("+", $this->products);

    return count($aProduct) > 1 ? false : true;
}

public function client()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Client::class, 'client_id');
}

public function cart()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Cart::class);
}

public function campaign()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Campaign::class);
}
```

And here is the model for the Product

```
class Product extends Model {
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 
    'ean',
    'category_id',
    'client_id',
    'init_price'
];

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'created_at', 
    'updated_at'
];

public function client()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Client::class, 'client_id');
}


public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(CategoryProduct::class, 'category_id');
}

public function productsId()
{
    return preg_split( "/(\+|\|)/", $this->products);
}
```

}

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you just need to use a many to many relation. not has many relation

Comment: Actually my problem is that I didn't build a relationship, I'm just wondering if I can build it dynamically in a query.

Comment: Updated my post to add both models.

Comment: what is the issue in having many to  many relation between `product` and `coupon` ? why use a string field to save multiple ids when you can have a table with an entry for each id (many to many relation with a pivot table `coupon_product`)

Comment: As explained above I was using a string field because I don't have a simple relationship and I need to store somehow this complexity. A coupon can be used with several combinations (for example productA or product B, but maybe also productA + productB) and I thought this way was simpler to manager these AND / OR differences.

Comment: What you are describing is exactly the relation `many to many`, consider checking this https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/help/18/fmp/en/index.html#page/FMP_Help/many-to-many-relationships.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199436/discussion-between-fabrice-lefloch-and-n69s).

Answer (score 0):

You should reconsider your database structure.

Coupon : Product is many to many relation.

That means they will be stored in a pivot table and you will be able to query as you want. Also, you could create a model for pivot table if it will help you to easier write queries.

Comment: OK, I was hoping there could be a way to simulate a relationship and keeping my actual structure.
But I do understand haw strange it is. 
After struggling a bit with this I think indeed that I'll have to update my database structure and use a pivot table. 
I'll have to think a bit about the structure of it since it's not a "simple" many to many relationship since I have to manage different kind of relations between several products and a coupon.
Thank for your answer.